# Using "main" for story board fails because View controller isn't the main story board

Tags: ios, swift

I embedded a page view controller into a container view. The View controller containing the Container view isn't the main View controller so my program crashes.

```
import UIKit

class CarsSwipe: UIPageViewController,  UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

  lazy var viewControllersList:[UIViewController] = {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "carsSwipe")

    let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blueView")
    let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orangeView")
    let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blackView")
    return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
   }()

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcIndex = viewControllersList.firstIndex(of:  viewController) else {return nil}

    let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}
    guard viewControllersList.count > previousIndex  else {return  nil}

    return viewControllersList[previousIndex]
   }

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let vcIndex = viewControllersList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {return nil}
    let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1
    guard viewControllersList.count != nextIndex else {return nil}
    guard viewControllersList.count > nextIndex  else {return nil}
    return viewControllersList[nextIndex]
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    if let firsViewControlller = viewControllersList.first {
      self.setViewControllers([firsViewControlller], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

}
```

I want the PageViewController to scroll in the container inside the View controller

Comment: Where does it crash?  What's the error/crash say?

Comment: is `CarsSwipe` in storyboard? or it's being created programmatically? if it's in storyboard is in the `main.storyboard` (lowercased 'm') file?

Comment: @Alastar it is the story board

Comment: @PhillipMills if says the identifier "main" can't be found

Comment: it is in the `main.storyboard` file or `Main.storyboard`?

Comment: I think I shouldn't use let "vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blueView")" because of this line "let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "carsSwipe")".

Comment: @Alastar Main.storyboard

Comment: Why are you using a named storyboard at all? View controllers have a `storyboard` property which is the storyboard for the current scene. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Diran that's the first error, see the answer for the second part

Comment: @Alaster. Thanks a lot. it worked like Fire

Comment: @Diran You're welcome! if it worked. accept the answer please

Answer (score 0):

the error is in this line:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "carsSwipe")
```

remove  `.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "carsSwipe")` and should compile successfully.

Cause `sb` in the code below isn't a `UIStoryboard` but a viewcontroller:

```
let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blueView")
let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orangeView")
let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blackView")
```